# Best & Recommended way to share resources like VPC, Security Rules between different AWS CDK Stack

Tags: typescript, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I want to setup a infrastructure for a client product and I need to share resources between different ECS Services like VPC, Security Group, RDS so I can avoid recreating EC2 instance
and assign a global accelerator to that ec2 instance for static ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particular barrier to sharing resources across stacks in the CDK. Just access the objects like any other object.

Create your shared resources in one stack, then simply access them from your other stacks. The CDK will automatically create necessary cloudformation exports and imports.

For example, suppose you create a stack `infraStack` which contains your vpc, security groups, etc as properties. You can simply pass your `infraStack` object to the constructor for your other stacks and access the resources in the other stack then use the objects like accessing any object like `infraStack.vpc`.

Alternatively, you can explicitly create the exports/imports. For example, you can use [CfnOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.CfnOutput.html) to output the id for a VPC. Then you can import this in another stack using `importValue` from [Fn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html) and use that with [`ec2.Vpc.fromLookup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html) -- or if you don't care about hard-coding the VPC id, just call `ec2.Vpc.fromLookup` and hard-code the VPC ID.